# React get form field value in onSubmit

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to understand pretty basic things but seems I'm lost trying to get form field value in onSave function. I have one field in form only `<input name='content'>`

```
_onSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var content = e.content.value;
```

but it respond in console with `TypeError: e.content is undefined`

Comment: `var content = e.target.content.value` where "content" is the name of your form field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get input's value using

```
e.target.value
```

Or

```
e.preventDefault()
let value = document.getElementById("myinput").value;
let valu2 = document.getElementById("myinput2").value;
...
```